# How to support AARs in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, gradle-eclipse

In the new Gradle build system, we can package Android projects in very convenient .AAR format.

Unfortunately the ADT Eclipse plugin, v22 , does not support this file format. Please can it do so.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to get Eclipse to use an AAR file at the present time.

Comment: @CommonsWare i need to integrate some library built by gradle in my project but i could not do that

Comment: Either switch to Gradle and Android Studio, or see if the project is available as an Eclipse-compatible Android library project.

Answer (score 2):

I am currently renaming .aar file as .zip and then extracting it.
After that I rename the classes.jar to jar file name I want. A bit tedious
but this is how I am currently using .aars file in eclipse.

Comment: Hi, am also using like this.but, while using any Activity from JAR , its showing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ActivityName.R$layout..also i included all extracted res,assets,mani files into library proj.